# Can someone tell me why this jQuery script does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code.

```
function switchbox(showall, maincls) {
    $(showall).change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(maincls).each(function(i) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        });
        } else {
        $(maincls).each(function(i) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        });
        }
    });
}

switchbox('.show-all-tags, .tags');
switchbox('.show-all-cats, .categories');
```

It works if i didn't use variables inside the function. It should disable all checkboxes of that class when the show-all-X is checked and vice versa. and i tried it without the variables showall, maincls it works. What I am doing wrong here please?

Thank you.

Comment: what is maincls? it seems that it isn't defined

Comment: oh silly me i forgot the quotes ahead of .tags, .categories.. so i suppose it was treating that as one variable. STUPID MISTAKE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maincls isn't being defined, maybe you meant:

```
switchbox('.show-all-tags', '.tags');
switchbox('.show-all-cats', '.categories');
```

Comment: Silly me... embarrassing :$ Thank you